# deleting groups

Tags: groups, smartgroups

under contacts, manage groups, delete; the following notiThis group currently has 35 members in it. Deleting this group will NOT delete the member contact records. However, all contact subscription information and history for this group will be deleted. If this group is used in CiviCRM profiles, those fields will be reset. This action cannot be undone.

Comment: Hi - welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange. I don't think you have asked a question, just described a message that you have received which is a standard warning message telling you what will happen when you delete a group. Can you explain what your problem is in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

if it helps ... 'subscription information and history' simply means the record of when someone was added to the group. no value in keeping this if you are deleting the group. you will not be deleting anything else about the Contact